# If my Corda root private key is compromised, how can I migrate my node's existing states to a new private key?

Tags: corda

If my Corda root private key is compromised, how can I migrate states to a new private key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To migrate states from the old key to the new key, you would have to write the states' contracts in a way that allows the state to be migrated in this way. As long as the contract allows states to be migrated from one public key to another, you will be able to migrate the states.

Note that as soon as your private key is compromised, you are in a race against the attacker. They will be trying to spend your states, while you will be trying to migrate them.

However, Corda does have several protections against attacks of this sort:

- In Corda, the attacker would need not only your private key, but also the contents of your vault. If the attacker doesn't know what states you have, they can't spend them (in traditional blockchains, everyone has everyone's information, so this line of defence does not exist)
- Corda has support for hardware security modules
- Corda will introduce support for human interaction in the future. Once this has been introduced, the attacker will need not only the private key and vault contents, but will also need to fool the human operator behind the UI